# Declared parameterized types in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

In OCaml suppose a type is given:

```
('a myTypeA) myTypeB
```

Is there a OCaml specific built-in, given a value `x` of type `'a myTypeA myTypeB` , to obtain a value `y` of type `'a myTypeA` (basically de-constructing the type and removing `myTypeB`)?

I'm looking for a function with signature:

```
val deconstruct : 'a myTypeA myTypeB -> 'a myTypeA
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a bit puzzling to read, because types in OCaml must start with a lowercase. Or are you indeed talking about constructors (ie values)? In that case, they can't be in a type expression.

Comment: @PathJ Sorry, edited! I'm working my way among many languages and sometimes these errors slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, unless you can see the definition of `myTypeB`, and here's why:

Nothing keeps you from creating the following types:

```
type 'a t = int (* here 'a is called a "phantom type" *)
type 'a u = unit -> 'a (* the type of functions that return an 'a *)
```

Now, there is no way to "extract" the `'a` value "contained". That is because a type parameter is not always "the type of value contained" but can indicate a wide range of different things (and in the first example, nothing at all).

If this seems restrictive, note that even in the case of containers, you may not want to allow that `deconstruct` function to exist as such. You can learn more about that if you start using [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

Comment: So if you're given a value of a type `'a t`and only a function `'a -> 'a t`, there is no way back, right? It seems strange that you can build values of that type but can't go back. Especially if you're building a monad (or applicative) and have to write a lift function from scratch.

Comment: @Pareto absolutely. Modules are usually used for that: you define a type and all the different ways you can interact with it.